# Differentiability of the distance function

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a geodesic distance function on a smooth Riemannian manifold $X$ ($d$ is determined by metric tensor) and $x \in X$ is fixed. What can be said about the points in which $f:=d(x,\cdot)$ is differentiable? In particular:
-is it possible that $f$ is everywhere differentiable?
-how big the set of points in which $f$ isn't differentiable can be?
-what can be said about the structure of the set of point in which $f$ isn't differentiable (can it be a submanifold?)
I would be grateful if anybody could shed some light on these issues.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21295

Answer (score 12):

Travis's examples have a general explanation - on any complete, connected $n$-manifold, the distance function $d(p,\cdot)$ is smooth everywhere except at $p$ and on the cut locus of $p$. (You can make this conclusion by studying the exponential map - see e.g. Chapter 5.9 of Petersen's *Riemannian Geometry*.)

Thus your question amounts to studying the structure of the cut locus, which has been the subject of a lot of research over the last few decades; so while I'm not too familiar with it myself, you should be able to find many relevant papers online. While the picture I have in my head of the cut locus is a submanifold, I'm pretty sure there are degenerate cases where you at least lose differentiability.

If I'm interpreting the main theorem of [this article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.tmj/1178224899) correctly, you *can* conclude that the cut locus has Hausdorff dimension at most $n-1$, and thus that the distance function is almost everywhere differentiable, which answers the "how big" question.

Comment: No, cut locus need not be a submanifold, just look at the 2d flat (product) torus. The cut locus will be the figure 8 graph.

Answer (score 5):

Except on $0$-manifolds, $f$ will never be smooth, or even $C^1$: In normal coordinates $(u^i)$ centered at $x$, $f(u) = \sqrt{u_1^2 + \cdots + u_n^2}$ for sufficiently small $u$, and so in particular $f := d(x, \, \cdot \,)$ always has an isolated singularity at $x$.

For $X = \mathbb{R}$, $$f(t) := d(0, t) = |t|,$$ which is nondifferentiable only at $0$, and $\{0\}$ is of course a submanifold. For $X = \mathbb{S}^n$, $f$ has discontinuities at $x$ and its antipodes. The only connected Riemannian $1$-manifolds up to isometry are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$, and so for such manifolds, the singularity set is always a submanifold, with one or two points. The second example shows that the singularity set can be a ($0$-)submanifold no matter $n$.

On the real projective space $\mathbb{RP}^n$, endowed with the metric induced by the round metric via the covering $\pi: \mathbb{S}^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$, at a point $[x] = \pi(x)$, the set of discontinuity is $\{ [x] \} \cup \mathbb{RP}^{n - 1}$, where $\mathbb{RP}^{n - 1}$ is the image of $(n - 1)$-sphere orthogonal to $x$ in $\mathbb{S}^n$, which shows that for $n > 1$ the singularity set is not in general a submanifold, and that it can have components which are hypersurfaces.

Answer (score -2):

For example, we can take a point $(x_0,\frac{1}{2})$ on $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$  and geodesics $y=\pm\frac{x_0}{2}x$. Obviously, for $x_0\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ these two lines are shortest geodesics. And if we move the point upper or lower, then the distance has a positive one-sided derivative and therefore is not differentiable at any point of $\{y=\frac{1}{2}\}$. The same for $\{x=\frac{1}{2}\}$.

Subset of singular points is not a subvariety.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise: by the geodesic distance I mean the formula: $d(x,y)=inf \ell(\gamma)$ over all piecewise smooth curves $\gamma$ joining $x$ and $y$. In sufficiently small open sets this infimum is realised by geodesic: geodesic is defined by the requirment $\nabla_{\gamma '}\gamma '=0$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection.